# Counting the unique values in a data frame and then appending the value in front of the string when grouped

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data frame:

| Name | id | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | alice_1 | (A_01), (A_02) |
| Bob | bob_1 | (B_01) |
| Alice | alice_2 | (A_01), (A_05) |
| Alice | alice_3 | (A_01), (A_05) |
| Bob | bob_2 | (B_01) |
| Bob | bob_3 | (B_01) |

I would like to count the unique model values inside the brackets and append the count in front of the bracket like that:

| Name | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 3x (A_01), 2x (A_05), 1x (A_02) |
| Bob | 3x(B_01) |

I tried to use different approaches with group by and aggregate functions but could not find a way. Also I can use value counts and count each Model but then I don't know how to append the resulting number the the whole data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for new rows by joinjed values by `,` , then get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), sorting and add to `Model` column, last aggregate `join`:

```
df = (df.assign(Model = df['Model'].str.split(', '))
          .explode('Model')
          .groupby(['Name','Model'])
          .size()
          .sort_values(ascending=False)
          .astype(str)
          .add('x')
          .reset_index(level=1)
          .assign(Model = lambda x: x[0].str.cat(x['Model']))
          .groupby('Name')['Model']
          .agg(', '.join)
          .reset_index())
print (df)
     Name                         Model
0  Alice   3x(A_01), 2x(A_05), 1x(A_02)
1    Bob                       3x(B_01)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)+[`explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), use a custom aggregation with help of [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

out = (df
   .assign(Model=df['Model'].str.split(',\s*'))
   .explode('Model')
   .groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Model']
   .agg(lambda g: ', '.join([f'{i}x {x}' for x, i in Counter(g).items()]))
)
```

Output:

```
    Name                            Model
0  Alice  3x (A_01), 1x (A_02), 2x (A_05)
1    Bob                        3x (B_01)
```

If you want the values sorted by frequencies (instead of the seen order), use `Counter(g).most_common()` in place of `Counter(g).items()`:

Output:

```
    Name                            Model
0  Alice  3x (A_01), 2x (A_05), 1x (A_02)
1    Bob                        3x (B_01)
```